Searching for contacts with apostrophes their name
We have a CiviCRM database in which a lot of the contacts are churches named after saints, e.g. "St. John's".
The problem is that any contacts that were entered directly into CiviCRM using the keyboard contain a straight apostrophe ('), but in many cases users have pasted the church name in from elsewhere and they instead contain a right single quote (’).
Is there any way to have CiviCRM treat the two characters as the same when using the default search box, so that churches will come up in the results list regardless as which character they use?
